# Unexpected comma using round() in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

```
$newprice = (round(floatval(trim(str_replace('$','',$mrow[3])))*.75), 2);
```

Works fine as a floatvar without the round() part, but says there is an expected comma when I try to round to two decimals.

Looks correct per the docs.. "echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96"

Anyone see the issue here?

Edit:

```
$newprice = (round(floatval(trim(str_replace('$','',$mrow[3])))*.75));
```

Works fine, but I need two decimal places.

PHP 7.0.5-2

Comment: Why the pointless parenthesis before `(round` ?

Comment: Your formatting is wack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.0.5-2

No need for trim as floatval will take care of it

```
$newprice = round(floatval(str_replace('$','',$mrow))*.75, 2);
```